# Preview ContentDocument Image in Lightning Web Component in a Lightning Community

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I need to have the ability to preview a ContentDocument image in a lightning web component. Apparently [lightning:fileCard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileCard/documentation) is not available for LWC yet and the [navigation mixin solution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_open_files) appears to not work if your lightning component is in a lightning community. There is also no thumbnail preview when you upload the document. Any ideas on a good work around for this? Any idea when/if this feature will be available? I'm currently creating a custom app for a client so I need to be able to say that it either isn't possible or there's a relatively easy way to implement it.

Comment: My use case was slighlty easier - we just loaded the ContentVersion via APEX for JPG/PNG only and then added `<img src` tags with the servlet URL.

Comment: @codermeow did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The NavigationMixin solution should work as well, with minor modification. According to this [blog post](https://www.sfdcpanther.com/how-to-preview-files-in-lightning-community-using-lwc/), rather than using NavigationMixin.Navigate with *type* argument **standard__namedPage** and ContentDocumentId, you should be using **standard__webPage** along with the file URL.

```js
    previewFile(file){
        
        if(!this.usedInCommunity){
            
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__namedPage',
                attributes: {
                    pageName: 'filePreview'
                },
                state : {
                    selectedRecordId: file.ContentDocumentId
                }
            });
        } else if(this.usedInCommunity){
            
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__webPage',
                attributes: {
                    url: file.fileUrl
                }
            }, false );
        }
        
    }
```