# How to view the content Document in Lightning Community

Tags: community, customer-community, contentdocumentlink

I have an option to Upload the document in the community Portal.

```
 <lightning-input type="file" onchange={handleFileChange} name="uploadFile" multiple label="Attachment">
              </lightning-input>
```

```
@api
    async handleFileChange(event) {
 this.attachmentArray = await Promise.all(
            [...event.target.files].map(file => this.readFile(file))
        );
        console.log("attachmentArray -->" + JSON.stringify(this.attachmentArray));
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(this.attachmentArray);
        console.log("myJSON -->" + myJSON);
        addAttachment({
            timebillingId: this.timesheetBillingId,
            strBase64: myJSON,
            loggedinUserId: this.recordId,
        }).then((result) => { 
........
........
```

**Apex Class**

```
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(w.base64);
cv.Title = documentName;
cv.PathOnClient = documentName;              
cverList.add(cv);
insert cverList;   

   list<contentversion> cvlist;
            if(  
                contentversion.SObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible()){
                    cvlist = [select id, contentdocumentid, Title from contentversion where Id IN:cverList];
                }
```

**Note:** From this point i can able to get the content document Id.

Attached document are Listing in the data table and On clicking of the attached document i need to preview the attachment.

Trying to frame the Content document as below

```
String fullFileURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
fullFileURL  = fullFileURL + '/lightning/r/ContentDocument/'+ cdt.ContentDocumentId +'/view';
```

The above URL is redirecting to below Page, Can anyone help Anything I am missing here.

[image]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the file URL and construct it as follows to get the file preview: 
`https://your-community-domain-url/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=<ContentVersionId>`

Then use `NavigationMixin` with `standard__webPage` to redirect to the file URL.

This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/332053) provides some additional info with link to this [blog post](https://www.sfdcpanther.com/how-to-preview-files-in-lightning-community-using-lwc/) for sample code.

This is to work around the fact that LWC [open files preview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_open_files) using `standard__namedPage` is not supported for Communities / Experience Cloud sites.

Note that you might want to check [`lightning-file-upload`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation) solution instead of using `lightning-input` for file upload.

PS:  there is an Aura component `lightning:fileCard` which allows to preview a file simply by providing the `ContentDocumentId` but this is not available (yet) for LWC, refer to [IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcxvUAB/lightning-web-component-for-lightningfilecard).

Comment: @SFDC_Beginner did this help ?