# File preview(pdf) in LWC for community

Tags: lightning-web-components, files

I'm trying to use the following URL format to preview file in LWC but however it shows only the first page as image not the entire file. Is there a way to preview the entire file and not just 1 page?

Preview_URL:

```
  /sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=
```

Comment: Does this answer your question [How to view the content Document in Lightning Community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/366588)

Comment: no, actually I'm using the same URL format and it displays only the first page as image

Comment: Have you implemented any solution for the same issue? Currently I'm facing same issue, I'm doing preview files using custom lwc component but pdf first page showing only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to request each page via the URL parameters:
e.g.

```
currentpage = 0;

get URL() {
return  '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=068XXX&page=+'currentpage;
}
```

To see more pages, you can give the user a previous and next button

```
<lightning-button class="slds-float_right" label="Next Page" onclick={nextPage}></lightning-button>
<lightning-button class="slds-float_right" label="Previous Page" onclick={previousPage}></lightning-button>
enter code here



previousPage() {
        if (this.currentpage >= 1) {
            this.currentpage --;
        }
    }

    nextPage() {
        if (this.currentpage >= 0) {
            this.currentpage ++;
        }
    }
```